# Worklight Studio 6.2.0.01 in Ubuntu not creating .xcodeproj

Tags: ios, ubuntu, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm using Worklight Studio 6.2.0.01 in Eclipse Luna and Ubuntu 14.04 (Also tested it in Ubuntu 12.02 and Eclipse Kepler).

I've followed the following steps to create a hybrid application with the iOS environment:

1. Create a Worklight Project
2. Create a Worklight hybrid application
3. New Worklight environment (iPad)
4. Run as -> Build All Environments
5. Run as -> Run on worklight development server

There are no errors in Worklight nor Server console

Problem: the native folder inside apps\my-app\ipad\native contains only 2 folders, and there's no [project].xcodeproj.

- Resources (empty)
- www
- Native Resources -> Resources (empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in Ubuntu and the iPhone environment's native folder was properly created.

As you wrote in your question, please double-check again with these more-precise steps:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Make sure you delete the tmp\wlBuildResources folder
3. Open Eclipse
4. Make sure the above folder is re-created
5. Create a project + app + iphone environment