# Worklight 6.2 not creating iPhone or iPad environments properly

Tags: iphone, ipad, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, rhel6

I'm using Worklight version 6.2.0.01 in Eclipse Luna and Linux RHEL6 and when I try to create a new iPhone or iPad environment, it is not creating the native project properly, it only creates the following folders inside apps\my-app\ipad\native:

- Resources (empty)
- www
- Native Resources -> Resources (empty)

I have already tried the steps described here in this post ([Worklight Studio 6.2.0.01 in Ubuntu not creating .xcodeproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956655/worklight-studio-6-2-0-01-in-ubuntu-not-creating-xcodeproj)), but it not worked for me.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the build number of your Studio installation?

Answer (score 0):

Go to IBM Fix Central website and make sure you download & install the latest available 6.2.0.01 iFix. This should hopefully correct this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to reinstall worklight.
im using Eclipse:
Version: Juno Service Release 2 and everything is fine.
don't forget right click on your app -> build and environments

hope helpful for you